# How to show last view controller with data in it after password form?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I have two storyboards. First is used for showing Password. It has two view controllers and own navigation controller. Second storyboard contains view controllers for app and also navigation controller. User should type in password every time he launches app if he wouldn't disable it in settings.

Here is my AppDelegate.m :

```
- (void)startApp
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([Security getUseOrNotPassword] || (NO == [Settings isNotFirstAppRun]) )
        [self showLoginScreen];
    else
        [self showMainVC];
}


-(void)showLoginScreen
{
    if (NO == [Settings isNotFirstAppRun])
        [Settings setDefaultLanguage];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Password" bundle:nil];
    PasswordVC *passwordView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];
    if (NO == [Settings isNotFirstAppRun] ) 
    {
        passwordView = [passwordView initForAction:PasscodeActionSet];
        [Security saveUseOrNotPassword:YES]; 

    }
    else 
    {
        passwordView = [passwordView initForAction:PasscodeActionEnter];
        passwordView.passcode = [Security getPassword]; //pass password to verify  
    }
    passwordView.delegate = self;
    UINavigationController *navigationController= [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:passwordView];

    [[(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:navigationController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

-(void)showMainVC
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    MainTableVC *mainVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"main"];
    LeftMenuVC *menuVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftMenu"];
    RevealVC *mainRevealController = [[RevealVC alloc] initWithRearViewController:menuVC frontViewController:mainVC];

    UINavigationController *navigationController= [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainRevealController];

    [[(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:navigationController];
}
```

*Here is delegate method from Password: if user type in "correct" password main screen is opening:*

```
- (void)PasswordVCDidEnterPasscode:(PasswordVC *)controller
{
    [self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self performSelector:@selector(showMainVC) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}
```

*And finally: displaying password every time when application become active*

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    [self startApp];
}
```

*My question is:*
 in this schema for displaying password form **how to show user's last view controller in which he typed something and data in it (text in textfields and etc)?** Because if user pressed Home button and after launched to app all data would be disappeared and there will be main screen of app=) **Maybe I should change the algorithm for showing password form?** *Thanks for answering and advising! Have a nice coding!)*

Answer (score 0):

The password form has nothing to do with this, once application is killed (which will be at some point, if it is in the background) the data in memory is lost.

First of all you will have to figure out a way to store (persist) the application's state. You can maybe do this with `NSUserDefaults` for very basic persistence, such as: user's last visited screen, last visited time, or similar.

But for more advanced persistence that stores the data user has entered you will have to code your own Data model. There are many ways to do this, so I can only give you some starting pointers:

- If you have relational structured data, use [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).
- For very basic storage you can also use **Property lists** and **files**.
- For synchronisation you can use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/ios) or [iCloud](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/) API's.

First you need to decide what you need and how are you going to approach this problem. You will need to write a little bit of code to get this all working properly.

Comment: No-no you didn't understand me exactly:)  I want to restore my view controller and data in it (text, etc) after I launched app:) but through my schema I should always go to main vc:) but I need to display last view controller:)